# Rails will not run server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails on my Win10 machine, and the server refuses to run.

```
$ rails server
Could not find server ''. (Rails::Command::Base::CorrectableError)
Run `bin/rails server --help` for more options.
```

I tried to find an answer, but can not find one. Yes I am in the project root.

Comment: Which rails version are you running? You can get it by doing `rails --version`. Don't know any rails version that might cause that error, but that could be useful for others to answer your question

Comment: @HugoDavidFarji `Rails 6.0.3.2` and `ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]`

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried specifying your server handler as discussed in [this article](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/08/07/explicit-rails-server-handler-option.html)?

Comment: @jvillian I just tried and it did not help. Is this Ruby version unusable with Rails? Because on the Rails website it said that it is.

Comment: Also had this issue running the dummy app inside of an Engine. Adding the webrick gem to the Engines Gemfile solved the issue.

Answer (score 23):

For people running Ruby 3.0, since Webrick isn't shipped by default anymore, if you still want to use it, you need to add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'webrick', '~> 1.7'
```

Answer (score 14):

Rails does not find a server to use, it happened to me upgrading a Rails 5.x to 6.x project. The way to solve was to add on my Gemfile:

```
gem 'puma', '~> 5.2'
```

Of course you could try different servers like `unicorn` or `thin` as @jvillian shared on his article.